# How do I form an alternate name for myself rooted to my mother's name (Meena)?

Tags: name

In ancient times children were given names derived from their parents' name. For example, Arjun was Kaunteya (from Kunti) and Karn was Radheya (from Radha).

Similarly, how would I form an alternate name for myself rooted to my mother's name, which is Meena?

Comment: do some research on Vŕ̥ddhiḥ gradation.

Comment: As **hard as it is to believe **, that is actually a compound using the taddhita affix "eya" https://learnsanskrit.org/start/words/secondary/

Comment: It also "strengthens" the first vowel to its strongest form. In your case it would be Maineya

Comment: from Mena comes Mainak..closer to your case..bdw ur Q is offtopic (personal advice) here..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comments, Hinduism ️, for a reason known only to the authors, thinks taddhita affixes are part of the religion.

[The Agni Purana details them](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083586.html)

---

Don't ask me why this is considered part of the religion. I don't know.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! We would prefer to have quoted reference with the link for the validation. link only answer is not good to have.